# Remove starting from end up to first close parenthesis

Tags: .net, regex

I asked this question [RegEx to match last occurence of semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459198/regex-to-match-last-occurence-of-semicolon/37459250?noredirect=1#comment62420484_37459250) and it worked well. For some reason I can't pinpoint I'm getting duplicate `; ;` at the end of my string.

To ensure the fix is universal I have one constant that will not change is the character preceding these double semi colons is a closed parenthesis `)`

How would I go about matching from the end of the string and stopping on the `)`

I was able to fix the problem using the following `;;[^;]*$`

```
AB12(1,2,3,4);AB12(1,2,3,4,5,6);;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search using this pattern:

```
^(.*\)).*$
```

And replace by:

```
$1
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qT6nS7/2)