# Changing the last semicolon that is followed by a string to another character

Tags: regex

I am looking for a pattern that changes the last semicolon to another character, 'x' for example

This is an example string where I want to change the last semicolon:

`Dabei(PROAV);dürften(V);einige(ART);frühe(ADJA);Investoren(N)`

I've tried a few things like this, but this is not working.

`^;(.*) or ;(.*)$ or ;[^;]*$`

PS: My question is not a duplicate of [RegEx to match last occurence of semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459198/regex-to-match-last-occurence-of-semicolon) because **in my case the last semicolon is NOT the last part of the string**. In my case, the last semicolon is followed by a string. So I want to change the last semicolon in a line that is followed by a string to something else.
Just like in my example `...;Investoren(N)` should be changed to `xInvestoren(N)`

Comment: If your regex engine supports negative lookaheads (most do) you can use `;(?!.*;)` to match the last semicolon. Changing it to `'x'` is something you do with the language you are using, referencing the regex. In Ruby, for example, you would write `str.sub(/;(?!.*;)/, 'x')`, where the variable `str` holds the string. The negative lookahead, `(?!.*;)`, asserts that the match of the semicolon is not followed by zero or more characters followed by a semicolon.

Comment: Another way is to use the regex `.*\K;` to match the last semicolon, provided that your regex engine supports `\K`, which causes the beginning of the match to be reset to the current location in the string and to discard any previously-matched characters. This works because `.*` is greedy, meaning that it gobbles up all semicolons that precede the last one, as well as other characters (other than newline characters).

Comment: You almost there. Just make your first semi colon to group like `;[^;]*$` to `(;)[^;]*$`. Now you can replace first group.

Comment: Looking at the duplicate, it you can use a capture group for the part after the semicolon, and use that in the replacement preceded by an x char. `;([^;]*)$` See https://regex101.com/r/pBOp5N/1

Answer (score 1):

**Find**: `(.*);`

**Replace**: `\1x`

This matches greedy everything till the last `;` in a group `\1`.

Comment: In the first what is the point of putting the semicolon in a capture group?